# Ubuntu calendar easteregg/spam?

Tags: firefox, calendar, easter-egg

When selecting a date from the Ubuntu calendar and drag into firefox it redirects to this page http://cdn.ruanjian.com/bibei/

Is this intentional?

Comment: What action are you talking about? Do you mean to open the calender in the panel by clicking the clock, selecting a date and dragging it to a firefox window and dropping it there? If I do this Firefox goes to the URL http://www.2011-08-11.com/

Comment: yes.. I'm talking about that.. but in my (Ubuntu 11.04 x64) it goes to the url in the question!

Comment: What happens if you type in `"http://www.2011-08-11.com/"` manually? Do other nonexistent URLs take you there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you

1. open the calender in the panel by clicking the clock,
2. select a date and drag it somewhere and
3. release it

then it's copied to where it's released.

For instance if release it into a text editor it inserts the date. This is just an example of a drag and drop feature.

The reason that you end up at http://cdn.ruanjian.com/bibei/ is, I guess, that an URL of the form http://www.2011-08-11.com/ (but not exactly this URL) links there.

Comment: if i release it in FF it goes to that url in the question (using Ubuntu 11.04 x64)

Comment: It may happen that your DNS redirects you from http://www.2011-08-11.com/ to http://cdn.ruanjian.com/bibei/ and ours not.